# PHP get each result from array and append it within div tags

Tags: php, arrays

this is my code:

```
    $searchfor = array();
    $searchfor[0] = 'INT.';
    $searchfor[1] = 'EXT.';

    // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    // escape special characters in the query
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor[0], '/');
    // finalize the regular expression, matching the whole line
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
    // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
        echo "<div class='int'>".implode("\n", $matches[0])."</div>\n";
    }else{
        echo "No matches found";
    }
```

How can i take the results and out each array item into an array of DIVs?

right now the output looks like this

```
<div class="int">INT 1</div>
INT 2
```

but I have like 150 instances of where INT. is found in my file so I was wanting to get it to show like this:

```
<div class="int" id="1">INT 1</div>
<div class="int" id="2">INT 2</div>
<div class="int" id="3">INT 3</div>
<div class="int" id="4">INT 4</div>
<div class="int" id="5">INT 5</div>
<div class="int" id="6">INT 6</div>
<div class="int" id="7">INT 7</div>
<div class="int" id="8">INT 8</div>
```

and so on...

Any suggestions?

UPDATED CODE:

```
    echo '<div id="int-div" style="width: 738px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; background-color: #FFF;">';
    $searchfor = array();
    $searchfor[0] = 'INT.';
    $searchfor[1] = 'EXT.';
    $searchfor[2] = 'I/E.';

    // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    // escape special characters in the query
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor[0], '/');
    // finalize the regular expression, matching the whole line
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
    // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){

        $row = 0;
        foreach($matches as $match)
        {
            echo "<ol><li><div class='int' id='".$row."'>".implode("</div></li><li><div class='int' id='".$row."'>", $match)."</div></li></ol>\n"; 
            $row++;
        }
    }else{
        echo "No matches found";
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

UPDATES RESULTS:

```
<ol>
<li>
<div class="int" id="0">INT. STRAWBERRY'S BEDROOM - MORNING</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="int" id="0">INT. PALO TORCIDO HIGH SCHOOL, CLASSROOM - MORNING</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="int" id="0">INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - MORNING</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="int" id="0">INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - MORNING</div>
<li>
<div class="int" id="0">INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - EARLY MORNING (FLASHBACK)</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="int" id="0">INT. FUENTES RESIDENCE, KITCHEN - NIGHT (PRESENT)</div>
</li>
<li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `foreach` and use the keys as your id:

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
{
    $row = 0;
    foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        echo "<div class='int' id='".$row."'>".implode("\n", $match)."</div>\n";
        $row++;
    }
}else{
       echo "No matches found";
}
```

Comment: oh, i did try a foreach loop but i forgot about they key value bit, well my loops was made a bit diff but i think i was in the right area. Um, just curious but it returns Array

Comment: it should have the exact same output as your original :/, `var_dump($match);` in your loop and update your post with the contents please.

Comment: i'm sorry, i got it to post as expected, Only problem is the $key is always at 0. I update with new code

Comment: `$key` can never always be 0, this would go against all programming laws, as `$key` is an index of the array they are unique, please post some sample html that was produced.

Comment: Updated to counter that,im not sure why this is happening but it must be from the regex :/

Comment: i cannot explain why this is happening unless you have been modifying the wrong code.

Comment: I edited with my current code, I don't see anything wrong tho and logically I agree with you that the counter should go up

Comment: are the results being cached ?

Comment: more than lily there being cached, try doing `myfile.php?_=1245356345`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid messy quote escaping and concatenation by creating a template string and using `printf()`.  Notice the placeholders and the two variables that relate to them.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N8CTE))

```
$matches = [
    [
        "INT. STRAWBERRY'S BEDROOM - MORNING",
        "INT. PALO TORCIDO HIGH SCHOOL, CLASSROOM - MORNING",
        "INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - MORNING",
        "INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - MORNING",
        "INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - EARLY MORNING (FLASHBACK)",
        "INT. FUENTES RESIDENCE, KITCHEN - NIGHT (PRESENT)",
    ]
];

$liTemplate = <<<HTML
    <li><div class="int" id="%d">%s</div></li>

HTML;

if ($matches) {
    echo "<ol>\n";
    foreach ($matches[0] as $i => $match) {
        printf($liTemplate, $i + 1, $match);
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}
```

Output:

```
<ol>
    <li><div class="int" id="1">INT. STRAWBERRY'S BEDROOM - MORNING</div></li>
    <li><div class="int" id="2">INT. PALO TORCIDO HIGH SCHOOL, CLASSROOM - MORNING</div></li>
    <li><div class="int" id="3">INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - MORNING</div></li>
    <li><div class="int" id="4">INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - MORNING</div></li>
    <li><div class="int" id="5">INT. DUNKIN' DONUTS - EARLY MORNING (FLASHBACK)</div></li>
    <li><div class="int" id="6">INT. FUENTES RESIDENCE, KITCHEN - NIGHT (PRESENT)</div></li>
</ol>
```